# How can users like each others post using sequelize postgres nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to implement that users can like each others post.

Here is my Likes model:

```
const Likes = db.define("Likes", {

id: {
allowNull: false,
autoIncrement: true,
primaryKey: true,
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
  PostId: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
   references: {
  model: "Post",
  key: "id",
   },
onUpdate: "cascade",
onDelete: "cascade",
 },
 userId: {
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
references: {
  model: "User",
  key: "id",
},
onUpdate: "cascade",
onDelete: "cascade",
 },
 createdAt: {
allowNull: false,
type: Sequelize.DATE,
 },
updatedAt: {
allowNull: false,
type: Sequelize.DATE,
  },
```

Here is my Post Model:

```
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
title: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
userId: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
},
```

Here is my Users Model:

```
id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
name: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
```

and here are my associations:

```
db.Likes.belongsTo(db.User, { foreignKey: "userId", targetKey: "id" });
db.Likes.belongsTo(db.Post, { foreignKey: "PostId", targetKey: "id" });
db.Post.hasMany(db.Likes, { foreignKey: "PostId", targetKey: "id" });
db.User.hasMany(db.Likes, { foreignKey: "userId", targetKey: "id" });
```

how should i go about and implement the like and unlike action?

is it supposed to be a get request or a post request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a like should be a `post` action to add a new association linking the user to the post. This should be one-to-one between user and post as you have suggested, since it should not be possible to like a post more than once.

Unliking is as simple as deleting the association, so you can test if a post is liked by a particular user by doing a `get` for an association between the user and the post in your likes intermediate table. If it doesn't exist, the user hasn't liked it (and should be allowed to like it) and vice-versa.

Comment: hi harry, in my association code above User and Post have a 1 to many relationship with likes not 1-1 should i change it?

Comment: No, it is the `User` and `Post` relationship that is one-to-one. A `Post` can have many `Likes` from different users, and a `User` can `Like` many `Posts` so that makes sense. To check if a user has liked a particular post, just query for a `Like` with the relevant `userId` and `postId`. To unlike, just delete the `Like` with that `userId` and `postId`.

Comment: But. user can have many posts, but a post belongs to one user, so it is a 1-many relationship as well

Comment: Those are two different things. The `Post` belongs to the `User` directly. But a `Post` has many `Likes` - there's an intermediate table (`Likes`) to differentiate the two.

Comment: i the associations code above is this association already there or do i need to add it?

Comment: i am trying to send the post request like this but it is not working: router.post("/:id/like", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req)
  Likes.findOne({
    where: {
      userId: req.body.userId,
      PostId: req.params.id,
    },
  });
});

Comment: I'd suggest marking this question as complete and opening a new question for that query, including the full code and error message.

Comment: @kd12345 Still make sense or you will create one more question?